# Как распарсить строку в LocalDateTime, если в строке не фиксированное количество цифр?

Tags: java, парсер, datetime, jdk11

Есть задача парсить строку-дату в объект типа `LocalDateTime`. Проблема в том, что строка может содержать от 1 до 9 цифр (миллисекунд) после точки. А может и не содержать миллисекунд, тогда точки в конце вообще не будет. Как правильно парсить в таком случае?

В данный момент была попытка это сделать так:

```java
String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSS]";

LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern));
```

Естественно, этот паттерн не захватывает все случаи, т.к. есть сомнения, что так делать в принципе правильно.

Так же пробовал паттерн `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.[S][S][S][S][S][S][S][S][S]]"`, но с ним в результате парса получается не та дата, которая в строке (думаю, из-за того, что одни `[]` внутри других не поддерживаются).

Код для проверки:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSS]";

        String dt_template = "2021-02-19T03:53:12%s";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (i > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append('.');
            }

            for (int digits_count = 0; digits_count < i; ++digits_count) {
                stringBuilder.append('3');
            }

            String dateString = String.format(dt_template, stringBuilder.toString());
            try {
                LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern));
                System.out.println(dt);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что если просто "добивать" нужные знаки? Тогда точка и отсутствие нулей будет без разницы. Нужен вспомогательный метод нормализации значения просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В лоб ты эту проблему скорее всего не решишь. Тут надо динамически формировать шаблон после оценки количества знаков для частей секунды. Иными словами, сначала оценить сколько знаков после точки, а потом сделать парсинг. Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        String f = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
        String t = "2021-02-19T03:53:12";
        String[] dtArr = new String[]{t, t + ".1", t + ".1234", t + ".123456789"};
        for (String dt : dtArr) {
            int ind = dt.indexOf(".");
            StringBuilder end = new StringBuilder();
            if (ind > -1) {
                end.append('.');
                int cnt = dt.length() - (ind + 1);
                char[] chars = new char[cnt];
                Arrays.fill(chars, 'S');
                end.append(chars);
            }
            String pat = f + end.toString();
            LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dt, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pat));
            System.out.println("nano = " + ldt1.getNano());
        }
    }
```